# Sprout SEO 3 with Craft Tags

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

ENVIRONMENT: Craft 2, Sprout SEO 3.4.2, Bob Olde Hampsink's "Tag Manager" plugin.

The site has a bunch of articles organized by category and tags, and I've got a template for showing articles by tag (ex: https://www.therapyinphiladelphia.com/tips/tag/employment/).

In Sprout SEO I've "Enabled Meta Details fields" and attached them to Craft's TAGS using the Tag Manager plugin. This allows me to insert custom metadata for each TAG just like I would on a normal Craft entry.

So in theory the `{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}` template tag on my "articles by tag" template should pick up the custom values entered into the Sprout SEO meta details fields for the tag... just like it would for a normal entry.

However it's not picking up anything, it just reverts to the Globals set under Sprout SEO's settings.

To debug I've done a couple of things:

1. Under Sprout SEO > Settings > Advanced > Enabled custom metadata variable (giving it the name `metadata`), and
2. turned on Craft's dev mode and echoed `{{ dump(metadata) }}` into the template.

The output of `{{ dump(metadata) }}` shows the Globals set under Sprout SEO's settings and not the custom metadata entered into the Tag Manager for the selected tag.

I've also tried using the `{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta() %}` function to manually override the automatic output of the `{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}` template tag.

```
{#
 # ARTICLES BY TAG TEMPLATE
 #}

{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}

    {% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({ 
      section: 'Self Help Tips',
      title: tag.title,
      description: metadata.metaDescription|striptags|slice(0, 150),
      canonical: craft.request.url,
      ogTitle: tag.title,
      ogType: 'article',
      ogUrl: craft.request.url,
      ogImage: metaImage.url(),
      ogImageWidth: metaImage.width,
      ogImageHeight: metaImage.height,
      ogImageType: metaImage.mimeType,
      ogSiteName: siteName,
      ogDescription: metadata.description,
      twitterCard: 'summary',
      twitterSite: '@twitteruser',
      twitterCreator: '@twitteruser',
      twitterTitle: tag.title,
      twitterDescription: meta.search.description,
      twitterUrl: craft.request.url,
      twitterImage: metaImage.url()
    }) %}
```

This works if I enter hardcoded strings in, but the `metadata` variable in the template doesn't pick up the custom metadata entered for the tag.

Is this a bug? Is the Sprout SEO plugin only set up to work with ENTRIES, and not TAGS?

Answer (score 1):

For any Elements that do not have URLs, like Tags or Users, you'll need to tell Sprout SEO what metadata to use.

Also, be sure that the `do craft.sproutSeo.meta` tag comes before the `{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}` tag. The do tag prepares the metadata for the optimize tag to process:

```
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({ 
  section: 'Self Help Tips',
  title: tag.title,
  description: metadata.metaDescription|striptags|slice(0, 150),
  canonical: craft.request.url,
  ogTitle: tag.title,
  ogType: 'article',
  ogUrl: craft.request.url,
  ogImage: metaImage.url(),
  ogImageWidth: metaImage.width,
  ogImageHeight: metaImage.height,
  ogImageType: metaImage.mimeType,
  ogSiteName: siteName,
  ogDescription: metadata.description,
  twitterCard: 'summary',
  twitterSite: '@twitteruser',
  twitterCreator: '@twitteruser',
  twitterTitle: tag.title,
  twitterDescription: meta.search.description,
  twitterUrl: craft.request.url,
  twitterImage: metaImage.url()
}) %}

{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}
```

We do have on our list to simplify this scenario and allow you to add an Element Metadata field to the field layout and just pass the `elementId`.

```
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({ 
      elementId: 123
}) %}

{% sproutseo 'optimize' %}
```